# Naming a bonus in a betting game creator

Tags: word-choice, word-request

What can I name the bonus that a betting game creator extra adds to the total stakes from his/her credits?

On this gaming website, a member can create a game with options for other members to place stakes on, and if the game creator wants to attract more players, he/she can add extra credits to total stakes in the game by deducting his/her credits in his/her account balance, so that winner(s) will get more credits after the game ends. How to name this bonus?

Because there are other bonuses on this website, e.g. Referral Bonus, thus I would like to name the bonus provided by a creator to distinguish different bonuses.

For examples:

> 1. Referral Bonus: When a member builds a new active downline member.
> 2. Recommendation Bonus: Share a link with your code to a betting game on this website to recommend people bet and attract more credits
>      placed from people than other recommenders.
> 3. `Raise Bonus(?)`: A betting game creator adds extra credits to the total stakes from his/her credits balance so that total stakes will be higher and attract players.

What can I name the bonus that a betting game creator (dealer) extra add to the total stakes from his/her credits? Raise Bonus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call it several different things, some you have already mentioned

> Dealer Bonus
>   Stakes Bonus
>   Added Bonus
>   Playing Bonus

are all possibilities.